# Should Global.asax.cs Application_BeginRequest get called for CSS and JS files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC3 I notice that Application_BeginRequest gets called for my CSS and JS files as well. My CSS and JS files reside in the /Content and /Scripts folders respectively.

Is this correct?  Is there really a need for these files to pass through the managed code pipeline?

The site runs on IIS7 (and the ASP.NET web server).

My modules configuration section looks as follows:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054440/beginrequest-fires-for-static-files-in-asp-net-mvc-app). Most probably you have same issue. If not then I would check your pipeline mode + handlers configuration.

UPDATE: sorry, just saw that you already have [runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"]. Do you use some profilers or custom virtual path providers?
In my case I use custom virtual path provider to serve files that are embedded into an assembly. For this purpose special configuration is created for a few subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr. No, I don't use any custom virtual path providers :(

Comment: could you add your "handlers" config section? And which pipeline mode you use?

Comment: Hi! Did you solve the problem? If yes then could you update your question to give more information to the users?

Answer (score 0):

Own answer:  In the end I could not figure out a way to not let static files go through the MVC pipeline. So I went for a hacky solution where I check the URL extension in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest and just return when static content is being requested (i.e. ".css", ".js" etc.)

Not pretty.